# Program will run the while loop, however will not run the function

Tags: c

I am quite new to coding in C and I have designed a program that does a certain task whenever the user inputs 1, 2 or 3. I have a data set of 80 X values corresponding to 80 Y values and firstly I need to; Find the min/max Y value and print that into a file with its corresponding X value, numerically integrate the dat file and then find the mean/std deviation of values. Basically this code that I have produced will run the program however, when inputting either 1, 2 or 3 it will not run any of the functions and will ask for another value.

Like I said, I am new to this so I know I'm not gonna get it first time.

```
#include <Math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
const int X = 1001; // will be used to define number of rows in array
const int Y = 2;    // equally used to define columns

void writeTwoToFile(int answer1, int answer2) {
    FILE* answers;
    answers = fopen("answer.txt", "w");
    fprintf(answers, "The first answer is: %d\n The second answer is: %d\n",
            answer1, answer2);
}
void writeToFile(int answer) {
    FILE* answers;
    answers = fopen("answer.txt", "w");
    fprintf(answers, "The first answer is: %d\n", answer);
}

void max(int dataArray[X][Y]) {
    int col = 1;
    int smallest = 0;
    int largest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        if (dataArray[col][i] > largest) {
            largest = dataArray[col][i];
        } else if (dataArray[col][i] < smallest) {
            smallest = dataArray[col][i];
        }
    }

    writeTwoToFile(smallest, largest);
}

void integrate(int dataArray[X][Y]) {
    int answer = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == 79) {
            answer += dataArray[1][i];
        } else if (i % 2 == 1) { //% is a modulo function, does a division and
            returns the remainder,
                easy way of alternating numbers-- answer += dataArray[1][i] * 2;
        } else {
            answer += dataArray[1][i] * 4;
        }
    }
    answer / 12;
    writeToFile(answer);
}

void mean(int dataArray[X][Y]) {
    int mean = 0;
    int stdDeviation = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        mean += dataArray[1][i];
    }
    mean / 80;

    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        stdDeviation += pow(dataArray[1][j] - mean, 2);
    }
    stdDeviation / 79;
    sqrt(stdDeviation);

    writeTwoToFile(mean, stdDeviation);
}

int main() {

    int loop = 0;        // act as a loop counter
    int user;            // to collect user input
    int dataArray[X][Y]; // array data is to be stored in

    // Open and read file
    FILE* data;
    data = fopen("data.dat", "r");

    // Read file in to 2D array, 2-1000 matrix essentially
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
            fscanf(data, "%1d", &dataArray[j][i]);
        }
    }

    printf("Welcome to this calculator, please input one of the following "
           "numbers\n");
    printf("1- Find maximum and minimum\n");
    printf("2- Find definite integral\n");
    printf("3- Calculate the mean and standard deviation\n");

    printf("\n");

    while (loop == 0) {
        printf("Please input the number you want to manipulate\n");
        scanf("%d", &user); // takes user input
        if (user == 1) {
            max(dataArray);
        }

        else if (user == 2) {
            integrate(dataArray);
        }

        else if (user == 3) {
            mean(dataArray);
        }

        else {
            printf("Please enter a valid number");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: C/C++ is not a language. Also provide [mcve] instead of this long code.

Comment: This should help you https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look.

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled, statements such as `answer / 12;`, `mean / 80;` etc. have no effect, you probably wanted `answer /= 12;`, and `mean /= 80;` etc. There are probably more issues though.

Comment: Write less code at a time. For example, you could write `max` and test it with hard coded values until you get the results you need. If you have a bug, you know it's in the `max` function, and that makes it a lot easier to track down than if you have to check five functions to look for the bug..

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you post a question, they belong to the site and its users. Even if it is no longer useful to you, it might be helpful to someone in the future. The answerers would have also put an effort in writing their answer, which would no longer be useful if you have removed the content from the post. Also, note that by posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: This: `#include <Math.h>` does not compile!  Perhaps you meant: `#include <math.h>` (all lower case)

Comment: Suggest using a `switch()` statement rather than testing `user` over and over

Comment: when calling `scanf()`, always check the returned value ( not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  IE. `if( scanf("%d", &user) != 1 )  { handle error }`

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  I.E. 12, 79, 80. 1000 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc. Suggest either using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: regarding: `else if (dataArray[col][i] < smallest)` and `int smallest = 0;`  This will NOT obtain the smallest number.  Suggest initializing `smallest` to `MAX_INT` from the header file: `limits.h`  and may have a problem if any of the numbers are < 0

Comment: this statement: `if (dataArray[col][i] > largest)` (and others) conflicts with the conventional usage of 'x' and 'y' in arrays

Comment: there are two places in the code that contain: `fopen("answer.txt", "w");`  First, the function: `fclose()` is never called.  Second, the "w" causes the file to be truncated to 0 bytes.  Probably not what you want.  Suggest: 1) open the file only once, in `main()`  2) before exiting the program, call `fclose()` on the file pointer.  Do not rely on the OS to clean up after your program.

Comment: the function: `printf()` is rather expensive in CPU cyles.  Suggest, for the menu, replacing the calls to `printf()` with calls to `puts()`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, including `fscanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when a C library function fails, call `perror()` to properly output a error message to `stderr`  (don't call `printf()` as that outputs to `stdout`

Answer (score 5):

You have an infinite loop.

The line of code:

```
while(loop==0)
```

in your main method will always evaluate true as you never increment the variable `loop`.

You should either use a for loop, or increment `loop` in each one of your input cases.